# In Grails, how do I search for something in the DB based on its discriminator?

Tags: grails, discriminator, grails-2.0.4

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
abstract class Fruit {
    String name

    static mapping = {
        discriminator column: 'type'
    }

class Banana extends Fruit {
    static mapping = {
        discriminator: 'Banana'
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
    static mapping = {
        discriminator: 'Apple'
    }
}
```

I need to implement a search algorithm such that, given a JSON string, I can find a particular Fruit instance in the DB. For example:

```
{
    "type": "Apple"
    "name": "Green"
}
```

or

```
{
    "type": "Banana"
    "name": "Green"
}
```

Problem is, fruits can have the same name, so if I just do a search for this:

```
Fruit.getByName('Green')
```

It might return the `Apple` or the `Banana`. I need to be able to filter it by its type as well based on the type, something like:

```
Fruit.getByNameAndType('Green', 'Apple')
```

How do I do this in Grails?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at  the generated database.

There will be a `class` column which you can use in a criteria search on your Fruit class.

Maybe this works as

```
   Fruit.findAllByColorAndClassLike('Green','%Apple')
```

too

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using `withCriteria`, which does support `eq('class', name)`, where name is the discriminator value.

Comment: @DanielT. Does `class` working for you? Since you have overridden descriptor column name to `type` in `Fruit` class

Answer (score 0):

```
Apple.getByName('Green')
```

Should work. Have you tried that?

Comment: I don't think you read the question thoroughly before answering. Please read it again and update your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hm. Would be interesting to see if you can do something like `def fruit = “Apple“; “${fruit}“.findByName(“Green“)`

Comment: Ralf: Just tried it out, apparently you can get it to work by using `grailsApplication.getDomainClass('com.example.Apple').clazz.findByName('Green')`. Note that the class name has to be fully qualified for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Should this meet your need?

```
def fruits = Fruit.findAll("from Fruit where type = :type and name = :name", [type: "Apple", name: "Green"])
```